# Append Date Created stamp to filename

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that will run on a folder and check the last modified stamp for each file in that folder then append that date to each file in the folder as it goes through them. For example:

IMG1_movie.mov

becomes

IMG1_movie_02032015.mov

There are a few examples online but the ones I've found don't cover the last modified date only appending the current date and none have batch capabilities. Any guidance is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write that part of the code as

```
new_filename="$(date -r $filename +%Y%m%d)"
```

where the `date` command arguments does the formatting for you. I made the format as `YYYYMMDD`. You could change the arguments to the order in which you want the date to appear.

Comment: I think they want to use the modified timestamp for the file not the current time.

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back, this was perfect for what I need many thanks.